# Integrating on a circle contour in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that the contour integral of a piecewise continuous function on a smooth contour is defined as:

$$\int_C f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$$

where $z(t)$ is the parameter of the contour. In the case where the contour is the unit circle, it is parameterized by $z(t)=e^{it}$ where the contour is from $0<t<2\pi$.

Does that mean if i want to integrate along the contour of the radius $2$ circle centered at the origin I would use:

$z(t) = \sqrt{2}e^{it}$, so that the modulus is equal to $2$ everywhere. And the integral would be from $a=0$ to $b=4\pi$ because that's the circumference of a radius $2$ circle?

Answer (score 1):

$|\sqrt 2 e^{it}|$ is $\sqrt 2$, not $2$  and the intergal is from $0$ to $2\pi$, not $0$ to $4\pi$. So you should get $\int_0^{2\pi}f(2e^{it}) 2ie^{it}dt$. Also the orientation make a difference. I have taken the anti-clockwise direction for the circle. For the clockwise direction yo get a negatiev sign.